# Talend - how to detect error in tFileInputRegex component

Tags: string, validation, talend

I am new to Talend, and I have to check the value from a txt file is only contain alphanumeric and special character. In this case, I am using `tFileInputRegex` component, and use the following regex: `"^[a-zA-Z0-9$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!/~  -]*$"`.

When I run the job, I can see the error throw when my file contains some `unicode`, like `◕☺`:

```
[ERROR] 18:20:18 orion_dl_track.jx_test_0_1.jx_test- tFileInputRegex_1 - Line doesn't match: f698fec0-dd89-11e8-b06b-â˜º
```

I would like to do something like, if I detect any error, then I want to stop the job, not proceed to next steps.

I am planning to use the `trigger Run if` to detect it, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make sure there is any non-whitespace char in the string, try `\S`, `[^ ]` or `^\s*\S.*`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, not the regex issue. My point is how am I going to know there is a error in this component checking, My intention is if it found regex error in the steps, then stop and not proceed to next.

Answer (score 0):

You can access component variables in the Outline tab (left side under Repository Tab).

[image: Component Tab]

You can use them by drag-drop into a tJava or similar (Talend will populate the correct syntax for you). You can use them wherever you'd like, including RunIf Trigger. Pay attention to the Before/During/After type of the variable you are using to ensure it is available and populated correctly when you call it.

Example using pattern that matches any line in file :

[image: RunIf Trigger: No Error]

Example using pattern that matches a line with pipe (not contained in file, will generate error):

[image: RunIf Trigger: Error]

You can also read the error if needed.

Comment: hi @OGmaps, this one only show the last regex error. I may get few rows of error in 1 file. Do you know how to do this? and is it able to tell which row, and which column character hit the regex error?